# R: charting a summed running total

Tags: r, plot

I have data in this format:

```
Count, Thread1, Thread2, Thread3, Thread4, 
10420162, 589768
46530936, 1164357
55563161, 275521, 12289
56741671, 25158, 28020
57792881, 44468, 91248
```

(As the additional threads come in to play, data appears in their columns)

I would like to plot the sum (running total) of the Thread data against the Count eg when x is 0, y is 0; when x is 10420162, y is 589768; when x is 46530936, y is 1754125; when x is 55563161, y is 2041935 and so on.

Not clear how I can do this - presumably it requires at least two steps - to sum the data and then plot it?

Comment: Would you like the threads to be summed too, or are you plotting each threat separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculated numbers don't match mine so I have a feeling I didn't understand your questions correctly. Or did you calculate it wrong?

```
df <- read.csv(tex`t`Connection('Count, Thread1, Thread2, Thread3, Thread4, 
10420162, 589768
46530936, 1164357
55563161, 275521, 12289
56741671, 25158, 28020
57792881, 44468, 91248'), header=TRUE)


dfcumsum <- data.frame(
count = df$Count ,
cumthreadsum = cumsum(rowSums(df[,-1], na.rm = TRUE))
)
```

Output -

```
> dfcumsum
     count cumthreadsum
1 10420162       589768
2 46530936      1754125
3 55563161      2041935
4 56741671      2095113
5 57792881      2230829
```

The most elementary plot would be `plot(dfcumsum$cumthreadsum)`

Comment: Apologies, there was an (smallish) error in my calculation of the final figure - not sure how I did that - now fixed.
I know how to read the csv data into a frame and it looks like you have identified the issue for me. I'll test it.